# How to set all values after specific value to 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to set all values in a row after a specific value to zero, and I am not sure how to accomplish this since that specific value will fall under a specific column referenced in the row. I will explain further with my example.

I have the following dataframe:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8     Select     Value  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0    54       33       46       23       35       22       36       36          3        46
 1    36       54       32       14       32       21       54       55          4        14
 2    34       29       11       14       21       29       33       46          6        29
 3    35       19       22       45       55       16       21       74          5        55
 4    27       39       43       22       22       24       22       55          3        43
```

The "Select" column contains the value corresponding to the column I want to reference. And so for each row, I want to set every value after the value in the referenced column to 0. The "Value" column contains that value, but for the purposes of this problem, will be ignored.

And so I am trying to produce the following dataframe:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8     Select     Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 0    54       33       46        0        0        0        0        0          3        46
 1    36       54       32       14        0        0        0        0          4        14
 2    34       29       11       14       21       29        0        0          6        29
 3    35       19       22       45       55        0        0        0          5        55
 4    27       39       43        0        0        0        0        0          3        43
```

As you can see, the value under the column referenced by the "Select" column was used as a point for which to set all values after to 0.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this in python? I am having trouble figuring this problem out since I am not sure how to reference values under columns that are indicated by a separate column. I am confused about how to get python to see a connection between the values under the "Select" column and the columns they are supposed to be referencing.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, filter the dataframe for numerical columns and use `.apply` where with boolean array *"mask"* the correct values:

```py
numbered = df.filter(regex=r"^\d+$").columns
nums = numbered.astype(int)

df.loc[:, numbered] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x[numbered] * (nums <= x["Select"]),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6  7  8  Select  Value
0  54  33  46   0   0   0  0  0       3     46
1  36  54  32  14   0   0  0  0       4     14
2  34  29  11  14  21  29  0  0       6     29
3  35  19  22  45  55   0  0  0       5     55
4  27  39  43   0   0   0  0  0       3     43
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, though I forgot to include a column in my dataframe. I have one more column that is the first column, right before the "1" column. Would that change how your code would work?

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis It shouldn't change how the code works. This example works only with *number* columns (1, 2, 3...) and "Select" column

Comment: I tried the code again and received the following error: `IndexError: ('only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices', 'occurred at index 0')`. Though if my columns are number from 10, 20, 30, 40 etc., would that cause the code to fail, instead of if the columns were just numbered 1,2,3,4 etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest way but it would do the trick. Also, the below covers your second requirement as well!

```
import pandas as pd

COLS = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'Select', 'Value']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=COLS,
    data=[
        ['54', '33', '46', '23', '35', '22', '36', '36', '3', '46'],
        ['36', '54', '32', '14', '32', '21', '54', '55', '4', '14'],
        ['34', '29', '11', '14', '21', '29', '33', '46', '6', '29'],
        ['35', '19', '22', '45', '55', '16', '21', '74', '5', '55'],
        ['27', '39', '43', '22', '22', '24', '22', '55', '3', '43'],
    ]
)

new_rows = []
def first_found_filter(rows):
    trigger_zeros = False
    new_row = []
    for col in COLS:
        if col == 'Select':
            break
        if col == rows['Select'] and rows[col] == rows.Value:
            trigger_zeros = True
        elif trigger_zeros:
            rows[col] = 0
        new_row.append(rows[col])

    new_row.append(rows['Select'])
    new_row.append(rows['Value'])
    new_rows.append(new_row)

df.apply(first_found_filter, axis=1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=COLS,
    data=new_rows
)

print(df)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming columns are numeric we can use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create the mask. Then use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to replace values with 0:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: [54, 36, 34, 35, 27], 2: [33, 54, 29, 19, 39],
    3: [46, 32, 11, 22, 43], 4: [23, 14, 14, 45, 22],
    5: [35, 32, 21, 55, 22], 6: [22, 21, 29, 16, 24],
    7: [36, 54, 33, 21, 22], 8: [36, 55, 46, 74, 55],
    'Select': [3, 4, 6, 5, 3], 'Value': [46, 14, 29, 55, 43]
})

# Get list of columns (can be done programmatically as well)
# cols = df.columns[0:8]  # (For example)
cols = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# Create Array representing the column space
# and compare to the values in Select Column
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(
    np.tile(cols, (df.shape[0], 1)) > df['Select'].values[:, None],
    0
)
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6  7  8  Select  Value
0  54  33  46   0   0   0  0  0       3     46
1  36  54  32  14   0   0  0  0       4     14
2  34  29  11  14  21  29  0  0       6     29
3  35  19  22  45  55   0  0  0       5     55
4  27  39  43   0   0   0  0  0       3     43
```

---

Mask creation:

```
np.tile(cols, (df.shape[0], 1))

[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]]
```

```
np.tile(cols, (df.shape[0], 1)) > df['Select'].values[:, None]

[[False False False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

---

In the event that column values are more complex and don't ascribe to specific ordering we can use [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) to convert to numeric values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': [54, 36, 34],
    'other col': [33, 54, 29],
    'yet another col': [46, 32, 11],
    'Select': ['col', 'yet another col', 'other col'],
    'Value': [54, 32, 29]
})

cols = ['col', 'other col', 'yet another col']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(
    np.tile(df.columns.get_indexer(cols), (df.shape[0], 1))
    > df.columns.get_indexer(df['Select'])[:, None],
    0
)
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   col  other col  yet another col           Select  Value
0   54          0                0              col     54
1   36         54               32  yet another col     32
2   34         29                0        other col     29
```

---

Mask Creation in the non numeric case

Convert string columns to numeric values:

```
np.tile(df.columns.get_indexer(cols), (df.shape[0], 1))

[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Compare to `Select` column converted to the same type of indexers:

```
(
        np.tile(df.columns.get_indexer(cols), (df.shape[0], 1))
        > df.columns.get_indexer(df['Select'])[:, None]
)

[[False  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False  True]]
```